# Proper way of reusing SqlConnection for page

Tags: methods, using, sqlconnection

I will try to describe it as simple as possible. We have `SqlConnection` and 3 methods.

**1st type**

This type open **one** SqlConnection and methods' have property SqlConnection. Basically they just use sConnection and within method the create, use, close SqlCommand and SqlDataReader

```
using (SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(string))
{
    sConnection.Open();

    Method objMethod = new Method();
    objMethod.SqlConnection = sConnection;
    objMethod.DoSomething();

    Method2 objMethod = new Method2();
    objMethod2.SqlConnection = sConnection;
    objMethod2.DoSomething();

    Method3 objMethod = new Method3();
    objMethod3.SqlConnection = sConnection;
    objMethod3.DoSomething();
}
```

**2nd type**

This type will create new SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader within every method separately. For 3 methods it will have to Open and Close 3 SqlConnections.

```
    Method objMethod = new Method();
    objMethod.DoSomething();

    Method2 objMethod = new Method2();
    objMethod2.DoSomething();

    Method3 objMethod = new Method3();
    objMethod3.DoSomething();
```

Question is whether to keep SqlConnection encapsulated within methods or is it safe to create on SqlConnection and use that opened connection within methods without need to open new.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Connections are pooled so if you are concerned with performance; chances are that both methods will use just one connection and therefore, the penalty for using the second approach is negligible.

On the other hand, the second approach shows better encapsulation and separation of concerns. I would go with the second option.

Answer (score 1):

SqlConnections are pooled.  With Sql Server you're best to open, use and close (which using block does - expands to finally with Dispose which calls close).

As a matter of fact, keeping the connection open and holding onto it can actually hurt performance since you're defeating the pooling behavior and causing other threads/requests to needless add another connection to the pool when it's not needed.

Let the pool do it's job.